# how to rotate an image continuously?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

I am trying to rotate this image by using a thread. what should I do?

```java
public class Start extends Activity {
    View base;
    Bitmap rotate, base1, rotate1;
    ImageView rotator;
    float angle, pivX, pivY;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);
        base = findViewById(R.id.base);
        rotator = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rotator);
        pivX = (rotator.getLeft()) / 2;
        pivY = (rotator.getTop()) / 2;
    
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (angle = 0; angle < 50; angle++) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    rotator.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX); // required
                    matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
                    rotator.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    if (angle == 40) {`enter code here`
                        angle = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                }   
            }
        };
        
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: added not working so many times. got tired of the message add some more text

Comment: Just try passing animation on view. Try out my post. Simply copy paste code and fallow instruction to have better understanding.

Answer (score 34):

use this code for rotating a button

```
btn_rotate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_rotate);
rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
rotation.setFillAfter(true);
btn_rotate.startAnimation(rotation);
```

### rotate.xml

put this file in res->anim->rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<rotate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

Comment: If you wish to do this using only java code then let me know i'll post it.

Comment: how to stop this animation

Comment: can you post it , want to do only with java code @Rajan

Comment: You can also set fillAfter in xml: `<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">`

Comment: but this animation is paused every turn. How to avoid it?

Comment: If I rotate multiple times, I get acceleration and decceleration, which looks ugly.

Answer (score 27):

I know it's probably late but here's how I do a rotate animation on java code:

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(
                0, 360,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f
        );

rotate.setDuration(900);
rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
itemImage.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: Not So Smooth! even after set to 1500 duration.

Answer (score 10):

Check this out ..

Your Java class ..

```
package com.example.rotate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {

    TextView txtMessage;
    Button btnStart;

    // Animation
    Animation animFadein;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        // load the animation
        animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.rotate);

        // set animation listener
        animFadein.setAnimationListener(this);

        // button click event
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // start the animation
                txtMessage.startAnimation(animFadein);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Take any action after completing the animation

        // check for fade in animation
        if (animation == animFadein) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Animation Stopped",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

your xml file ..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And one more thing .. you need to define **anim** folder in your **res** folder.

now place rotate.xml file in **anim** folder.

rotate.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="600"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>

</set>
```

That's it. you are good to go.

Comment: @OmidOmidi   you can manage the speed by changing the value of   android:duration , Higher the value is , lower the speed will be

Comment: I found that the interpolator needed to go in the animation set to be effective.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Kotlin with Android API 29:

```
val imageViewAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView,View.TRANSLATION_Y, 30f)
    imageViewAnimator.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
    imageViewAnimator.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE
    imageViewAnimator.duration = 1500
    imageViewAnimator.start()
```

The result of this code is a 'slow bouncing' infinite animation, but you can modify it as you wish using the [ObjectAnimator](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-property-animation/#0) properties.

Answer (score 0):

### In Kotlin:

```
 ivBall.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

            //Animate using XML
            // val rotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.rotate_indefinitely)

            //OR using Code
            val rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(
                    0f, 359f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f

            )
            rotateAnimation.duration = 300
            rotateAnimation.repeatCount = 2

            //Either way you can add Listener like this
            rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {

                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
                }

                override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
                }

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {

                    val rand = Random()
                    val ballHit = rand.nextInt(50) + 1
                    Toast.makeText(context, "ballHit : " + ballHit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })

            ivBall.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)
        })
```

rotate_indefinitely.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension in Kotlin :

```
fun ImageView.rotate(){
val rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(
    0f, 359f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f

)
rotateAnimation.duration = 300
rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {}
    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {}
    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {}
})
this.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.planet);

img.animate().rotationBy(3000).setDuration(60000).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).